# What is Optimal Way to Hover Image Buttons for Fastest Results - CSS, jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, hover, head

I apologize in advance for the general, possibly vague question but it's been on my mind lately.

Currently I employ several buttons that upon hover the image changes (in a few sites).  Some are subtle and have background colors change, some have CSS pseudo class hover entire images and some use jQuery hover method.  It seems certain things require different tactics.  But upon examining these as a whole, it seems I didn't really use a consistent method.

My question is, what is the best way to do this, in general, so as to make the page the fastest and to be consistent?  Even though it works OK, it seems not the best practice to have many calls to images in my CSS files.  Maybe I'm wrong.

But yet, if I have lots of jQuery scripts running, that seems contra-indicated too.  I look at other sites and they seem to have more `*.js` files rather than the scripts running in the `<head>`.  For example, currently, I have a header file that has most of my jQuery scripts.  I do this because I was always taught to keep these scripts in the `<head>` tag.  For example, is it better to add the scripts closer to the HTML code for readability?

Should I move the JavaScript out into their own files and just includes those in the `<head>`?  My pages work relatively well, but I have not been able to successfully say I have a framework for this phenomenon.  I'm trying to improve my strategy for this kind of work before I go and refactor these pages.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: Use css whenever is possible, for those hovering buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  What about if I want some easing or fading into and out of the button hover?  I have usually used jQuery for this.

Comment: ups, my bad, the corect link is http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2010/01/css-transitions-101/ , that link remaind in my clipboard. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do no not include js files in head, use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) or head.js to load your js files asynchronously.

Use only CSS for the hoover and merge all images into a sprite, this way you'll get a faster page load.

Comment: I ended up going with head.js, which is great.  I then enabled caching on the server and created several sprites from similar images.  The increase in performance is already noticeable.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should put common functionality in separate `.js` files because the browser can cache them. If you instead cut-and-paste the same js function into each HTML file, the browser will need to download it with every page (at least on the first load). Also, it's obviously going to be *much, much* easier to maintain!

And I'd be inclined to use `css` where you can, because at least it'll work when a user has JavaScript disabled (assuming their browser actually implements all the latest css features, which they might not!).

Comment: This is a good point.  I have a noscript file in there as well, for when JS is diabled, so it'd be nice if the buttons worked if JS is disabled.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create fading effect using css as well. If you are using images for different background color, then don't. You can get good background colors and effects on hover using CSS.

```
<ul class="nav-fade">
   <li>Home</li>
   <li>Tutorials</li>
   <li>Articles</li>
</ul>
```

CSS to fade this menu

```
.nav-fade li {
   background: #fff;
   padding: 3px 8px;
   display: inline-block;
   transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: background .25s ease-in-out;
   }

   .nav-fade li:hover {
      background: #ddd;
      }
```

src: http://bavotasan.com/2011/a-simple-fade-with-css3/